# ASP.NET MVC3 - Html.RenderAction not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing a layout page in MVC application. The layout page has 
- Header 
- Content
- Footer

Header has ogo, Welcome message, user info, several other links.

My question is, Should i design header as partial view or render it using Rendoraction. PartialView is working fine. But as this data does not depend on rest of the page, i want to call a controller action which returns a header view with its own model.

but HTML Rendor action is not working.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<body>
    <div class="main_page">
        <div id = "header">
            *@Html.Partial("HeaderPartial", @Model)*@
            @Html.Action("Header")
        </div>        
        <div id="body">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
</body>
```

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult Header()
{
  Var VModel = //Create Model;
  return View(VModel)  
}
```

**header.cshtml**

```
@model VModel
<div>
</div>
```

Error executing child request for handler

> System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `header.cshtml` look's rare to me, but if you want to make your header view as a partial view

First:

```
Remove the layout using

@{
    Layout = null;
 }
```

Second To render this view on your layout use

```
@Html.Action("Header","Home", new { foo= @someElement}) <-- this element send values to your action
```

Comment: I removed the layout as you said on header.cshtml and used '@Html.Action("Header", "Home")'. I'm still getting same error - Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Comment: Code is same as above.  
  
**IN Layout.cshtml** I'm calling action method  
  
    @Html.Action("Header", "Home")  
**ActionMethod in HomeController gets called**  
    public ActionResult Header()   
    {   
      Var VModel = //Create Model;   
      return View(VModel)     
    }   
  
but breaks after returning the view(VMModel) with below error  
 Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'

Comment: change the call from `Action` to `RenderAction` and put a try and catch to the whole controller

Comment: adding to that error message, this is the new error message i'm currenlty getting  
  
 error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"}

Answer (score 3):

Since the `Html.Action` call is in the layout page you have to specify the controller

```
@Html.Action("Header", "SomeController")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `RenderAction` call it like this in _Layout.cshtml

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Header", "Home"); }
```

Comment: I tried that too, but i'm still getting the same error

Error - Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.